# Finite group containing a normal copy of $S_3$ is a cartesian product

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Suppose that $G$ is a finite group and $N \triangleleft G$ is an isomorphic copy of $S_3$. Is it true that we can write $G \simeq H \times N$?

I cannot find a counterexample (at least using standard examples). I'm trying to prove that but I did not have good ideas. Probably this is not a hard question, so I'm satisfied with a hint.

Comment: This is more generally true for any *complete* group $N$. Here $N$ is complete if $Z(N) = 1$, and all automorphisms of $N$ are inner.

Comment: You might be interested to know that this property actually characterises complete groups. In other words, a group $G$ is complete if and only if, whenever $G \cong N$ and $N \unlhd H$, it follows invariably that $N$ is a direct factor of $H$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. Let $E$ be a group with $N\lhd E$, $N\cong S_3$.
Let $\varphi\colon E\to Aut(S_3)\cong S_3$ be the conjugation action on $N$ and let $K=\ker\varphi$. We have that $N\cap K=Z(N)=\langle 1\rangle$, and $\varphi(N)\cong S_3$. This shows that $E/K\cong S_3$ and that $KN=E$. Thus $E=N\times K$.

As mentioned by Andreas Caranti, this argument works whenever $Z(N)=1$ and all automorphisms of $N$ are inner.

Comment: Thanks to you (and Andreas) I learned something new today. I had somehow avoided meeting this fact before.

Comment: Thank you! In fact group actions answer many interesting questions.